# Awk script not reading an input file to execute

Tags: awk

I'm having trouble finding out how to read in my file into my `awk` script. 
This is what I have so far. Basically, I want to print out the header, and then read in the roster file which then I will edit to the necessary format. However, my problem is just figuring out how to read in the file.

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {print  "Last Name:First Name:Student ID:School – Major:Academic Level:ASURITE:Email" "\n" } {print $1,$2} roster
```

On running this

```
awk -f script.awk
Last Name:First Name:Student ID:School – Major:Academic Level:ASURITE:Email

^C
```

This is what I end up with - the file doesn't read in and I have to CTRL-C my way out since it doesn't close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is right, but the place where you have mentioned the input file `roster` is wrong. Move it out of the script. You need to understand that `awk` syntax is always as below

```
awk <action> <file>
```

The `<action>` part could be directly given in the command line or provided from a script using the `-f` flag. But the `<file>` argument still needs to be given no-matter which way. Moving it inside the script, makes `awk` wait for an input to read its standard input but it doesn't get any.

```
awk -f script.awk roster
```

You could modify the `script.awk` to just use `awk` without `-f` and use the `/usr/bin/env` for the shell to get the location of `awk` to execute

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk

BEGIN {
    print  "Last Name:First Name:Student ID:School – Major:Academic Level:ASURITE:Email" "\n" 
} 
{
    print $1,$2
}
```